# CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME issue if number is UNKNOWN

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am working on the recentcall list of android device and i am getting one problem with the **CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME**

there can be two cases of recent call that number can be in contact list name or it can be unknown. so if name will be exist in the contact then it will be displayed in **CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME** but if it is unknown number then what value it will give?

because if i compare that if **cached name** is null then i am putting number as a name but in simulator it works fine but when i install it in **samsung galaxy ACE DUOS**, if recent calls have unknown number then it crashes.

For example,
Recent call is **ABC : 888-888-8888**, **XYZ : 999-999-9999**
then it will work fine.

But if it will be **NO NAME : 444-444-4444**
then it will crash.

Anyone can tell what can be the problem with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a same problem when I tried to get phone numbers from call log who had no name. The `CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME` didn't return any value, even null.
After a while I solved this problem by bilding this cursor:

```
Cursor c1 = SetStatsView.this.managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, 
                                           new String[]{CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,  
                                           CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.DATE}, 
                                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME+" is null", null, null);
```

It return only the numbers without contact name.

Answer (score 0):

I have Done this work in the following way as mentioned. You don't need to create new query just use a condition to handle null value see the code bellow

```
Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null,null);
String Name;
List<String>NameHolder=new ArrayList<String>();
int nameValue=mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
 while (mCursor.moveToNext()){
             String name=mCursor.getString(nameValue);
                   if(name==null){
                       Name="Unknown";
                       NameHolder.add(Name);
                                 }
                       else {
                           Name=name;
                           NameHolder.add(Name);                                 
                             }
                 }
```